# Issue with Jest and ES6 syntax

Tags: javascript, jestjs, ts-jest, babel-jest

I have two test files that both use `import`. One of them passes, the other throws an error:

```
node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/blocks.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import deprecate from 'util-deprecate';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

    > 1 | import { DocsPage, DocsContainer } from '@storybook/addon-docs/blocks';
```

I've got Jest configured like so:

```
module.exports = {
  collectCoverageFrom: ['**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}', '!**/*.d.ts', '!**/node_modules/**'],
  coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
      branches: 80,
      functions: 80,
      lines: 80,
      statements: -10,
    },
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@app/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/$1',
    '^@components/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/components/$1',
    '^@graphql/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/graphql/$1',
    '^@lib/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/lib/$1',
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/',
  ],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$': ['babel-jest', { presets: ['next/babel'] }],
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/'],
};
```

I'm completely baffled at how one file can run fine while another can't. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Jest 27.x.x has become stricter in it's implementation.

I had a similar situation when I used a markdown npm package.

Try changing:

```
transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/'],
```

to:

```
transformIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/', '<rootDir>/node_modules/util-deprecate'],
```

Jest has [this](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#transformignorepatterns-arraystring) on their website where they explain how this issue can crop up.

And here's an explanation of the issue copied verbatim with the important bits highlighted:

> Sometimes it happens (especially in React Native or TypeScript projects) that 3rd party modules are published as **untranspiled**. Since all files inside node_modules are not transformed by default, **Jest will not understand the code in these modules**, resulting in syntax errors. To overcome this, you may use `transformIgnorePatterns` to allow transpiling such modules.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't resolve it. :( I was pretty hopeful too, it makes total sense and seems like it would solve the problem.